# How was cast selected in the show Louie?

Tags: character, production, casting, louie

What was the criteria for selection of cast with such variety in the TV show [Louie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1717353/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_15)?

Louie CK's casts [Amy Landecker](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0484541/?ref_=tt_cl_t4) as *young Louie’s mom* [S01E011, S04E11/12], [after already using her a few episodes earlier to play adult Louie’s blind date](http://uproxx.com/sepinwall/interview-louie-creator-star-louis-ck-on-season-one-drunken-sarah-palin-tweets-and-more/) [*Sandra* S01E09]. Is there any incoherence in this?

Another actor he places in different unexpected and unrelated roles  is [F. Murray Abraham](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000719/?ref_=tt_cl_t1)
who plays as a Swinger, *Jonathan*, in [New Jersey/Airport [S02E13]](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2037574/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_6), and then as 
*Uncle Excelsior* in [Dad [S03E08]](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2260198/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_6), and later on as his *Dad* in *In the Woods: Part 2* [[S04E12]](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3759210/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_6).

He also casts [David Lynch](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000186/?ref_=nv_sr_1) but to play an acting part, instead of directing...

What is the inspiration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [Louie CK's words](http://uproxx.com/sepinwall/louie-gym-night-out-here-stands-a-man/):

> *This show doesn’t really function as a series. I don’t think of it that way. I use what I need to tell each story*.

In the same source the writer notes in the same site [UPPROX news] that:

> CK and FX have referred to this show as **a collection of short films** before.

Answer (score 2):

The choice of Lynch is almost certainly a commentary on the conventional talk show format.  (Lynch is most known for making films about nightmarish situations.)  I don't know if CK has commented on conventional talk shows, but he has expressed his dislike of conventional sitcom formats...